# InAppBrowser close() freeze UI

Tags: user-interface, typescript, ionic2, inappbrowser

My application is using Ionic 2. When a user launches, they are met by the splashscreen. After a few seconds an instance of InAppBrowser launches for them to login to a company portal. Once the browser is redirected, the browsers listens for the 'loaderror'. At which point the browser closes, and Splashscreen.hide() is used. 9 times out of 10, the UI is frozen and the user tap or touch anything on the screen. If I put a done button to close the browser manually, 5 times out of 10 the UI freezes. My code is below:

```
public freshPOST() {
    //declare ESO login page as well as open Inappbrowser
    var url_code: any;
    let url = "CLIENT_AUTH_ENDPOINT_URL";
    let browser = new InAppBrowser(url, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=yes,enableViewportScale=yes,toolbar=no');

    //on redirect browser shows load error, and not url
    browser.on("loaderror").subscribe((event: InAppBrowserEvent) => {

      //pull code from url and store in variable
      let token = event.url.split('=')[1].split('&')[0];
      url_code = token;
      localStorage.setItem('url_code', url_code);

      //SETUP FOR POST
      //headers to be sent
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

      //parameters for POST request
      let details = "code=" + url_code + "&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&grant_type=authorization_code";

      //POST request with parameters injected
      this.http.post('CLIENT_TOKEN_ENDPOINT', details, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
        data => {
          //convert response to string, pull access token, and store in variable
          this.data = JSON.stringify(data)
          var access_token = data.access_token;
          var expires_in = data.expires_in;
          var refresh_token = data.refresh_token;

          //store all responses to local storage for retrieval
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
          localStorage.setItem('expires_in', expires_in);
          localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refresh_token);

          //launch app
          //write to console success
          //close browser
          console.log("Successful POST and Authentication");
          browser.close();
         Splashscreen.hide();
        },
        (err) => {

          //POST Failure
          //close browser
          console.log("post didnt work");
        });
    });
  }
```

I am launching this from App.Component, and only if platform is ready. The first page is an intro page that you skip to get to the tabbed view. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: So I have narrowed this down a little. The only time to replicate the bug 100% is to tap on the input box in the website. If I run through the entire process, without every clicking inside the inappbrower input box, the app never freezes. Could this be a focus thing? The user is required to sign in through the web, to access the application, so I am guessing that the input box is still what the app is focusing on, even when the browser closes.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I am also stuck on this same issue. I am using Cordova 7.0.1 with Node 2.14.7 and Angular 1.6.4. I've tried messing with the view controller referenced in the hide method of the native code but the issue is still happening, just inconsistently.

Comment: In my case, the staging environment provided for me contained a bug. The focus would never be removed upon hitting that authentication wall, thus keeping the application from seeing that the browser had closed. Taking the Splashscreen.hide() out of platformReady, and placing it in the POST request seemed to help.

Comment: A workaround on this, is physically pressing the close button on the browser. This refocused the user on the application, and prevents from this bug occurring.

Comment: One thing which I noticed is that there isn't actually the need to remain focused on the input box. In my case it is happening whenever I focus on an input, blur the input and close the browser via the button. Testing on google.com.

Comment: also having this issue. did someone solve programmatically ?